# Recompile/rebuild node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm fairly new with node.js. How can I recompile/rebuild to make changes in node_modules folder to take effect in my app? I just need to add a few temporary console.log lines to understand a module better.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is an  interpreted language so there is no need to recompile files in `node_modules`. For debugging you can simply navigate to the module you need to debug, add your `console.log` statements and you're ready to go.

It's a bit trickier if you use some C++ addons, but in most cases editing `.js` files is enough

Comment: This is incorrect, if the package has build scripts then you will need to rebuild the source files

Comment: @Edward OP asked about rebuilding the node_modules. node_modules is not source files, it's a folder with external dependencies that are already built. Sure you might have some scripts that modify/move content of node_modules before running, but that's not "building" from the source files and normally that doesn't happen when you just run your code locally for debugging